# Is it possible to save sidebar-[Specialised File].php into a sub folder and still call the sidebars?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created several 'sidebar-[Specalised File].php' files, where I have uploaded them to:
/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/THEME-NAME
To call the relevant Sidebar Templates, I have inserted the following code into my index.php and footer.php files:

```
<?php get_sidebar( 'body-content-left' );  //index.php
<?php get_sidebar( 'footer-left' );  //footer.php
```

In the interest of keeping my files organised, is there a way to be able to create a 'sidebars' folder, where I can then place all of my Sidebar Templates, and still be able to call these files?  I tried the following code but to no success:

```
<?php get_sidebar( 'sidebars/body-content-left' );  //index.php
<?php get_sidebar( 'sidebars/footer-left' );  //footer.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution, use `get_template_part( 'sidebars/sidebar-body-content-left' )` and the result will be the same.

Comment: Thank you Bidzina.  Achieved exactly what I was looking for.